# Is a certain inverse image under an equivariant map a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $G$ is a Lie group and $K$ a maximal compact subgroup of $G$, and suppose $G$ acts smoothly and properly on a manifold $X$.

**Question 1:** Suppose we are given a $G$-equivariant smooth map $f:X\rightarrow G/K$. Is $S:=f^{-1}(eK)$ necessarily a submanifold of $X$?

**Question 2:** If $X$ is now a manifold with boundary, then is $S:=f^{-1}(eK)$ a submanifold with boundary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f:X\to G/K$ is smooth and $G$-equivariant, with $G$ a Lie group and $K$ a closed subgroup. Then, in particular, $f$ must be a submersion: if $p\in X$ and $g\in G$, then $f(gp)=gf(p)$, so $f(\exp(t\xi)p)=\exp(t\xi)f(p)$.

Thus, $f^{-1}(gK)$ is a submanifold for every $gK\in G/K$.

Comment: Thanks, why does $f(\text{exp}(t\xi)p) = \text{exp}(t\xi)f(p)$ mean $f$ is a submersion?

Comment: Differentiating shows that $f_*$ is surjective. Note that this does not hold when $X$ is a point, but works whenever it has positive dimension (this was implicit in my answer).

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow: It actually works even if $X$ is a single point.

Comment: That it's a submersion? Why...Oh. Right. It's still G-equivariant. You are correct.

Comment: If $X$ is a single point then unless $G = K$, there can't be a $G$-equivariant $f:X\rightarrow G/K$, since such an $f$ would not be well-defined.

Comment: @ougoah Exactly.